# How change Visual Studio Desginer events?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winforms, visual-c++, clr

Is it possible to change how the events on a button in the visual studio designer will work?

For example, when you double-click on button1 (to get a button1_click), visual studio designer creates the following code:

[image]

"MyForm.h"

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
}
};
```

[image]

However, i would like visual studio desginer create the following code:

"MyForm.h"

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e);
```

"MyForm.cpp"

```
System::Void MyForm::button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What error compiler gives when you make changes as you want ?

Comment: I don't get any errors, it works, I would like to know if it is possible to make these changes automatically when adding an event.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same behavior when using **Wizard** ?

Right click on your button

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have these options. I am not using MFC, I am using CLR Empty Project (.NET Framework).